# React Formik reset after submission or closing

Tags: reactjs, formik

is there a way to call formik.resetForm()

from parent component ?

I have form but i would like to reset it only when submit is successful

Or everytime formik is closed

Is there a way to achieve this ?

```
onClick: (values, { setSubmitting, resetForm }) => {
         
              return onSubmit(
                 values,
                setSubmitting
              ),
              resetForm()
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the form in the submit function. You can pass the second parameter which contains a set of formik functions

```
const handleFormSubmit = (values, onSubmitProps) => {
   //Api call to submit the form

   // On success
   onSubmitProps.resetForm({ values });

};
```

Ref: https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#onsubmit-values-values-formikbag-formikbag--void--promiseany

Comment: also i send function handleSubmit to formik from parent

onClick: (values, { setSubmitting, resetForm}) => {
         
              return(
               onSubmit(values)
              ),
              resetForm()
            }

Comment: Can you share the complete code where you are making the form submission.